# SELECT in XML Field is slow

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, procedure

I'm writing a SQL Server 2005 stored procedure but the select on xml is really slow.

This is my code:

```sql
INSERT INTO @T    
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        tr.ID, tr.Identificazione as identification,
        ft.NumeroFattura, ft.IDFattura,
        dbo.getInvoicePayedStatus(ft.IDFattura)
    FROM 
        TestReport AS tr
    INNER JOIN 
        Job AS j ON j.ID = tr.Job
    INNER JOIN 
        Plan_Main AS pm ON pm.TESTREPORT = tr.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        Fatture AS ft ON ft.IDFattura IN (SELECT T.N.value('(text())[1]','int') 
                                          FROM XMLDATA.nodes('InvoiceList/id') AS T(N))
WHERE 
    tr.DocumentStatus = 4 
    AND j.NomeCliente = @companyId 
    AND ft.IDFattura IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    tr.id ASC
```

and this is the part that slows my stored procedure:

```sql
(SELECT T.N.value('(text())[1]','int') 
 FROM pm.XMLDATA.nodes('InvoiceList/id') AS T(N))
```

An example of the xml:

```xml
<PrecedentTask />
<UsedResources />
<InvoiceList>
    <id>4350</id>
</InvoiceList>
```

The number of row's is relative small after the "SQL Where" (about 30) but the query requires more than 8 seconds!

I also tried with the "=" operator instead "IN" and the performance is great (less than 1 second) but when my xml's "invoiceList" contains more than one row it doesn't work.

Do you have any solution ?

Comment: How the `Fatture` is linked to any of the other tables in the `JOINS` ? Also do you know the scalar function in your Select query `dbo.getInvoicePayedStatus()` is being executed to the each row being returned by the select query? get rid of the UDF and use a join.

Comment: Fatture is linked only with the xml inside the Plan_Main.XMLData and i know that dbo.getInvoicePayedStatus is executed but this is not a problem because this funcion it's fast.
Anyway, I said that with the equality operator the query results to be fast

Comment: And the data in the `Fatture` table is it linked to any of the tables in the joins before you join it to `Fatture` table ? It must be because you are joining this table with the other tables to get the final result set ?? Otherwise it is giving you a cross join of the result set of all the joins between other tables and of `Fatture` table, this could be the very reason your query is slow.

Comment: I've solved simpling changing to 'INNER JOIN Fatture as ft on ft.ID_Job=j.ID and ft.IDFattura IN     (SELECT TOP(1)T.N.value('(text())[1]','int') FROM pm.XMLDATA.nodes('InvoiceList/id') AS T(N))'
Thank'you @M.Ali!
But i cannot explain how this is possible.. why with "=" operator the function it's fast and with "IN" no?.

Comment: Using TOP 1 you have only shoved the actual issue under the carpet but not resolved it, Please see my explanation in the answer. Thank you.

Comment: ops, the "TOP(1)" is a copy and paste mistake.Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment your query is returning matching rows between the following tables.

```
TestReport as tr
INNER JOIN Job       as j  
on j.ID = tr.Job            -- Only matching rows betwwen "TestReport" & "Job"
INNER JOIN Plan_Main as pm 
on pm.TESTREPORT = tr.ID    -- Only matching rows betwwen "TestReport" & "Plan_Main"
```

But when you join the above tables with the `Fatture` table with NO defined relation between any of the above mentioned tables and the Fatture table

It actually `corss joins` the `result set` returned from the above joins and the `Fatture` table where the IDFattura is in the XML document.

I would say your problem is the JOINS not the query shredding XML.

You need to define a relationship in the `ON` clause when joining to `Fatture` table and filter out the rows using the same IN (subquery) in the ON clause or in the where clause.

Something like...

```
FROM TestReport as tr
INNER JOIN Job       as j  on j.ID = tr.Job
INNER JOIN Plan_Main as pm on pm.TESTREPORT = tr.ID
INNER JOIN Fatture   as ft on ft.IDFattura =         --<-- A column to join it back to any of the above tables                          
WHERE tr.DocumentStatus = 4 
  and j.NomeCliente = @companyId 
  and ft.IDFattura is not null
  and ft.IDFattura IN  (SELECT T.N.value('(text())[1]','int') 
                        FROM pm.XMLDATA.nodes('InvoiceList/id') AS T(N))
ORDER BY tr.id ASC
```